# Magento Custom Category for New Products

Tags: magento

Help: I create custom category for all New Products setted New from date and New to date. 
I write this code in Custom Layout Update:

```
<reference name="content">
   <block type="catalog/product_new" name="product_new"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"></block>
</reference>
```

I see it is displaying all new products but there are some problems:

1. There is Note Message: "There are no products matching the selection." even all new products are populated in the category
2. Toolbar Sort dropdown when select to any attributes no changes such as Sort by Name or Sort by Price

Please note that I create New.php located in core local folder and there is sort function

```
->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code ,i hope  it will show sort order

```
<reference name="content">
        <blocktype="catalog/product_new" name="product_new" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>

        </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: The issue is the sort not functioning. I mean if you sort by price then after process by JS then it is not sort from lowest to highest price. Same also sort by name it is not sort from A - Z